# How to constrain a type field to a power of two in a type system?

Tags: typescript, haskell, constraints, coq, type-systems

There is this in some JavaScript code:

```
function allocate(bits) {
  if ((bits & (bits - 1)) != 0) {
    throw "Parameter is not a power of 2";
  }
  ...
}
```

Essentially, there is a **constraint** on the input `bits`, that it is a power of two. Or instead of calling it a "constraint", you could say there is a validation on the input that it is a power of two.

Sidenote, I saw in [SQL](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3811831/Using-Check-Constraints-to-Validate-Data-in-SQL-Server.htm) you can do these sorts of constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Payroll 
    (
     ID int PRIMARY KEY, 
     PositionID INT, 
     Salary decimal(9,2),
     SalaryType nvarchar(10),  
     CHECK  (Salary > 10.00 and Salary < 150000.00) 
    );

ALTER TABLE dbo.Payroll WITH NOCHECK  
  ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_Payroll_SalaryType_Based_On_Salary
  CHECK  ((SalaryType = 'Hourly' and Salary < 100.00) or
          (SalaryType = 'Monthly' and Salary < 10000.00) or
          (SalaryType = 'Annual'));
```

But in both the SQL and JavaScript examples, this code executes at runtime to check if it is valid. I'm sure of the JS, not totally sure of the SQL, but I imagine it is a runtime thing.

What I'd like to know is how in a robust type system such as TypeScript or some other [programming language with types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_by_type_system) you can express this "power of two" constraint. Ideally so it is a compile-time constraint. Is this possible? If so, how is it done in some language? Any language will do, mainly looking for inspiration on how to implement this in a custom language with its own type system. Not entirely sure how this would work as a compile-time constraint. It is a "type", the "type of power of two integers", but not sure how to express that.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the *presentation*. Just specify a value `2^i` as `i`. So you pass `3` instead of `8`, and when you need to perform arithmetic you thus calculate the power of two. That way everything you represent with `i` is a valid power of two.

Comment: That's a good simplification perhaps, would maybe work for this specific case, but what about if the type was for an email address formatted string? Same sort of problem, looking for a general solution with application more than just this instance.

Comment: In `coq` you can use something like `Definition Pow2 := { n:Z | exists k, n=2^k } .` (can't remember the exact syntax) which is guaranteed  to contain a power of two. However, every single time you need to produce a value in the `Pow2` type you'll need to manually write a mathematical proof that your `n:Z` is indeed a power of two. If you can do that, you get the static guarantee. To efficiently run the program, you can `Extract` from the `coq` code an Ocaml program which will perform the computation with no runtime check for the "power-of-two" parts.

Comment: Just brainstorming: May be with isabelle theorem prover (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_(proof_assistant)).

Comment: You may want to look at https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/, where you can represent constraints much like in @chi's example.

Comment: "looking for a general solution with application more than just this instance" -- the idea of using a better data type _is_ a general solution.  Just as you would need different constraints on "power of 2" vs "string as email address", so too would you need different presentations of data, but that doesn't make the _idea itself_ less general.  Good use of ADTs allow correct by construction data, which is, indeed, what you're asking for.

Comment: "the idea of using a better data type is a general solution" is not true. In certain simple situations like the example presented here you can of course just store the power, but OP is clearly asking for a general technique to define subset types via arbitrary predicates. In general you can't just do "good use of ADTs": non-dependent ADTs are strictly less powerful than the ability to define subsets like the coq example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn’t exactly a single best method of solving this, since there are a variety of approaches with varying tradeoffs. Here are a few major styles used in Haskell.

### “Correct by Construction”

Instead of accepting a more general type like `Int` and trying to constrain it after the fact, introduce a type that can *only* represent valid powers of two, either by encapsulating the validation:

```
allocate :: PowerOfTwo -> …
```

```
module PowerOfTwo
  ( PowerOfTwo  -- Abstract type
  , powerOfTwo  -- Smart constructor
  , toInt
  ) where

newtype PowerOfTwo = PowerOfTwo Int

powerOfTwo :: Int -> Maybe PowerOfTwo
powerOfTwo n
  | isPowerOfTwo n = Just (PowerOfTwo n)
  | otherwise = Nothing

toInt :: PowerOfTwo -> Int
toInt (PowerOfTwo n) = n
```

Or by the principle of **make invalid states unrepresentable**, which can sometimes be done by convention:

```
-- | @'allocate' n@ allocates @2^n@ bits…
allocate :: Word -> …
```

Or structurally:

```
allocate :: PowerOfTwo -> …
```

```
-- | This type can /only/ represent 2^n.
-- (Ignore for the moment that it’s quite inefficient!)
data PowerOfTwo
  = One
  | Twice PowerOfTwo

toInt :: PowerOfTwo -> Int
toInt One = 1
toInt (Twice n) = 2 * n
```

### Proofs and Singletons

Along with an input, require a proof that the input has *already* been validated by the caller; a proof is just a value that can only be constructed if you perform the validation.

In the simplest case, this is identical to the `newtype` solution above: `PowerOfTwo` is a pair of an `Int` and an implicit proof that it’s been validated.

But you can also make those proofs explicit, which is often done in dependently typed languages, but can be done in any language with a way of representing existential types, as in the [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library or [Ghosts of Departed Proofs](https://kataskeue.com/gdp.pdf) style:

```
-- A type-level proposition that n is a power of 2.
data IsPo2 n

-- A classification of whether a value is a power of 2.
data WhetherPo2 n
  = Po2 (Proof (IsPo2 n))
  | NotPo2 (Proof (Not (IsPo2 n)))

-- Assertion that proposition ‘p’ is true.
data Proof p = TrustMe

-- Encapsulated validation, like above,
-- but now it gives back a “proof” value.
validate :: Named n Int -> WhetherPo2 n
validate (Named n)
  | isPowerOfTwo n = Po2 TrustMe
  | otherwise = NotPo2 TrustMe
```

In order to call ‘allocate’, you must give a proof that you validated the input:

```
allocate
  :: Named n Int
  -> Proof (IsPo2 n)
  -> …
```

And the only way to get one is from `validate`:

```
-- ‘name’ from the paper gives a type-level name to a value.
name 64 $ \ n -> case validate n of

  -- If we got a proof, we can proceed.
  Po2 p -> allocate n p

  -- Calling ‘allocate’ would be a type error here.
  NotPo2 np -> …
```

Dependently typed languages like Idris and ATS often use this style, with syntactic sugar like implicit parameters to help reduce the noise of passing these proof values around.

### Refinements

Some languages and tools like [LiquidHaskell](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/) incorporate solvers for *refinement types*, which are types like `Int` refined with *propositions* about them. Here, the input of `allocate` could be given a type like `{ n:Int | isPowerOfTwo n }`, which is a more compact way of encoding the proof above.

A refinement type checker typically uses a combination of explicit proofs, implicit flow-sensitive analysis, and numerical solving (SMT) to verify that you have tested the conditions that ensure the propositions hold. This style has the advantage of being easy to read, but unfortunately it can be hard to predict when verification will fail with heuristic solver-based approaches for complex propositions.

---

Something I like about all of these styles is that they don’t need to repeatedly perform validation; once you have a *proof* that some invariant holds, either as a structural invariant or a literal proof object, then you can *assume* it holds, and use more efficient code that would otherwise be unsafe.

Comment: I think it's important to draw a distinction between the newtype/ghosts of departed proofs techniques and the liquid haskell/dependent types techniques, namely that the former doesn't really do any proving (it just passes around a type parameter saying "the programmer promises they have checked this invariant holds"), whereas the latter approaches can genuinely check that your invariant holds semantically.

Comment: @oisdk: Yeah, that’s true, although GDP is sort of a middle ground in that you *can* do arbitrary honest-to-goodness proving *atop* whatever you’ve asserted as axioms or rules defined as `constⁿ TrustMe`. But while dependently typed languages and LiquidHaskell ultimately have the same thing at some level, it’s usually much more carefully tucked away in the language and standard library, which makes a qualitative difference.